# Is there a way to join multiple queries and add a column to the data that is an array of which query that data came from?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Edit 1: So far I have come up with the following SQLAlchemy in testing, but I still need to find out how to add to it the final SELECT that puts the data into the form I want. Any ideas?

```
query1 = db.session.query(literal_column("'first_name'").label("matches"), models.User.id).filter(models.User.first_name == 'Joe')
query2 = db.session.query(literal_column("'last_name'").label("matches"), models.User.id).filter(models.User.last_name == 'Su')

union = db.union_all(query1, query2)
results = db.session.query(db.alias(union, name='users')).all()
```

Please forgive me as I try to explain this as best I can. I haven't tried anything, if anyone asks. I have found no information that directly state if or how this can be done.

The main question is how can I take multiple smaller queries to a table and combine them so that the resulting data has a column (With the data it contains most likely an array) that is a list of queries that returned that same object.

For example if I have a table called Users with the following data

```
id | first_name | last_name | age
1  |Joe         | Shmoe     | 39
2  |Marry       | Su        | 63
3  |Frank       | Su        | 39
```

and I have the following queries (using SQL for simplicity but this should end up using PostgreSQL ORM style code)

```
Select * from Users where first_name = "Joe"; 
 - resulting Ids: 1
Select * from Users where last_name = "Su";
 - resultings Ids: 2,3
Select * from Users where age ="39";
 - resulting Ids: 1,3
```

The combining query should end up with

```
id | first_name | last_name | age | matches
1  | Joe        | Shmoe     | 39  | ['first_name', 'age']
2  | Marry      | Su        | 63  | ['last_name']
3  | Frank      | Su        | 39  | ['last_name', 'age']
```

If this is possible, how would one go about it?
Also to note. I would like to be able to specifically label what goes into matches.  For example I could label the first query 'first_name' like in my example or could be made 'firstName' or 'Dude', or what ever I desire.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do this:

```
select id, first_name, last_name, age, array_agg(m) matches from (
    select 'first_name'::text m, * from users where first_name = 'Joe'
    union all
    select 'last_name'::text m, * from users where last_name = 'Su'
    union all
    select 'age'::text m, * from users where age ='39'
)   d 
group by id, first_name, last_name, age;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finnaly came up with. No idea if it is the best solution, but it works.

```
queries = []
queries.append(db.session.query(literal_column("'first_name'").label("m"), models.User.id.label('id')).filter(models.User.first_name == 'Joe'))
queries.append(db.session.query(literal_column("'last_name'").label("m"), models.User.id.label('id')).filter(models.User.last_name == 'Su'))


union = db.union_all(*queries)
alias = db.alias(union, name='users')

query_results = db.session.query(alias.c.id, func.array_agg(alias.c.m)).group_by('users.id').all()
results = []
for result in query_results:
    results.append({'id':result[0], 'matches': result[1]})
```